# Prove that the IVP has a unique solution on $(-\infty,1)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP:

$\frac{\operatorname {dy}}{\operatorname {dx}}=y^2$;$y(0)=1;(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$

Prove that the IVP has a unique solution on $(-\infty,1)$.

$\frac{dy}{y^2}=dx$. On solving we get $y=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$.Thus IVP has unique solution for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$

Where am I wrong?Help needed.

Comment: Here, you have proven existence of a solution, not that "there can be only one" (unicity).  Do you know (and are you allowed to invoke) the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)?

Comment: I don't know much about it.Can you please give a solution using that theorem@ClementC.

Comment: Observe that $x=1$ is the point of discontinuity.

Comment: @Quintic;then how to find unique solution from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several statements of the Picard–Lindelöf theorem (also known as the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem). The one I know is the following:

> Let $D \subseteq \Bbb R \times \Bbb R ^n$ be an open set and assume $f : D \to \Bbb R ^n$ be continuous and locally-Lipschitz with respect to its second argument.
>
> Consider the Cauchy problem $y' = f(x,y)$, with $y(x_0) = y_0$.
>
> Then for every $(x_0, y_0) \in D$ there exist a maximal (with respect to inclusion) interval $I$ with $x_0 \in \mathring I$ and a *unique* $\varphi : I \to \Bbb R ^n$ verifying the given Cauchy problem.

In your problem, $f(x,y) = y^2$ which is easily seen to be locally-Lipschitz (but not globally so!): let $r>0$ and pick any point $b \in \Bbb R$ and consider the neighbourhood $(b-r, b+r)$ around it; then

$$| f(y_1) - f(y_2) | = | y_1 ^2 - y_2 ^2 | = \\ | y_1 - y_2 | \cdot | y_1 + y_2 | \le | y_1 - y_2 | \cdot (| y_1 | +  | y_2 |) \le 2(b+r) | y_1 - y_2 | \ \forall y_1, y_2 \in (b-r, b+r) ,$$

which shows that $\forall b \in \Bbb R$, $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $(b-r, b+r)$ with Lipschitz constant $2(b+r)$, i.e. it is locally-Lipschitz.

You have correctly computed a particular solution and its domain of definition, $\varphi : (-\infty, 1) \to \Bbb R, \ \varphi (x) = \dfrac 1 {1-x}$, so in your problem $I = (-\infty, 1)$. Note that $I$ is indeed maximal: to the left there is $-\infty$, so you cannot extend $I$ to the left anymore; to the right $\varphi$ becomes infinite in $1$, so you can't extend $I$ to the right, either. Then the theorem guarantees the uniqueness of the solution on $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $z:I\to\mathbb R$ is another solution of the same IVP. Then
$$
(z-y)'=z^2-y^2=(z-y)(z+y).
$$
Setting $w=z-y$ we observe that $w$ satisfies the IVP
$$
w'(x)=\big(y(x)+z(x)\big)w(x), \quad w(0)=0.
$$
Thus multiplying by $\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^x -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}$ we get
$$
\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^x -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}\big(w'(x)-\big(y(x)+z(x)\big)w(x)\big)=0
$$
or equivalently
$$
\Big(\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^x -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}w(x)\Big)'=0.
$$
Thereofore $\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^x -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}w(x)$ is constant in the interval $I$ and consequently 
$$
\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^x -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}w(x)=\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^0 -(y(t)+z(t))\,dt}w(0)=0,
$$
which means that $w(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$. Equivalently $y(x)=z(x)$, for all $x\in I$.